# Compare two datatables based on a single column

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to compare two datatables based on a single alpha numeric ID column. I know you can merge and then get differences, but as I understand it that only works if the tables have the same columns, which these don't.

My end result would be table 1 with all the matched ID from table 2 removed.

Table1

```
ID   Name   Amount
A3   Bob    43
B4   Jane   51
A2   Greg   52
```

Table2

```
ID   Code     Name   Location   Amount
A3   ABC123   Bob    Here       43
A2   CBA321   Greg   There      52
```

Result

Table1

```
ID   Name   Amount
B4   Jane   51
```

Comment: Join the two tables on the ID and then remove all from first table that have a matching field on the second table

Answer (score -1):

This bit of SQL should do what you want:

```
delete from table1  from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: sql I understand, but how would I apply this to a vb.net project?